# PHP exec doesn't return output

Tags: php, windows, exec

I've a program which must be runned from cmd.exe and be supplid a few parameters. The command looks like this:

```
query.exe USERNAME PASSWORD WMI_QUERY MACHINE
```

This program is working fine. But when I try to run it from PHP with the following code:

```
function execute_query($ip, $username, $password, $query){

    $runCMD ="query.exe " . $username . " " . $password .  ' "' .$query . '" '  . $ip;
    echo exec($runCMD);
    print_r ($stdout);
}
```

I don't get any output. It says that the process terminated successfully, but nothing else, although the program runs and returns the output successfully. I'm using windows and XAMPP with php 7.1
I tired using shell_exec, but didn't have any luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: `exec()` returns output in an array for each line of output in the terminal. iirc shell_exec does not return anything. check the array param that is passed by reference - http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: also $stdout is not defined

Comment: woops, ignore my first comment, i don't know why I thought shell_exec doesn't return anything, but $stdout is still not defined

Comment: You're not actually executing your `$runCMD`.

Comment: It didn't run $runCMD because I was testing.I tried creating var $output = [] and set it as second argument, but it was empty when I printed it.

Answer (score 1):

I usually simply use:

```
passthru("the_command 2>&1");
```

the 2>&1 bit is to redirect STDERR to STDOUT, which is where your output probably is, when the command fails...

Comment: also, to capture the output you can use ob_start() and ob_get_contents()